# Xpages getting filtered data in a view without a search box

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-domino

I'm new to Xpages and i'm currently learning how to work with it, I'm using the newest version of domino database and domino designer.
I have created a view which has column (can't post a picture)

```
[Name][Date from][Date to][Value][Name of the driver]
[#####][02/01/2015][NULL][######][#######]
[#####][02/01/2015][NULL][######][#######]
[#####][02/01/2015][05/05/2015][######][#######]
```

Everything works.
But now what i want is every time i open this view i want it to show data that has a NULL value in Date to. That would mean that the third row won't be shown in the view. The reason is that when i work that each document that has a NULL value in Date to has to be edited and must be given a value by end of the day, and removed from the first view.
How can i do that, can you give me an example or a guide where i can find a solution. I searched everywhere and can't find anything.

Comment: Do not try to alter your current view. Make a new one, name it "Needs review" and use @Rob's advice.

Comment: There is also another option - use first categorized column dividing documents to "OK" and "Not OK" categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you change the view Selection formula to exclude all documents that have a Date To set e.g. append `& DateTo = ""` or `& @Text(DateTo) = ""` to your formula?  It will probably be something like: `SELECT Form="DriverForm"`.  Sorry, I can't remember whether the `@Text` part is required, but you could try both and see which works.

Answer (score 0):

Could you base your XPage on a Full Text Search? There is an "IS PRESENT" option to look for non blank fields.  I assume you can negate that as well.  Some good searching information on this blog post:  http://lostinxpages.com/2014/05/15/exporting-to-excel-using-queries-in-xpages/